# How to group different rows from same IQueryable

Tags: c#, iqueryable

I have an IQueryable that contains the list of usage data in my application. Each row in it is a separate entry in the table. The structure is like this

{

### Usagedata

Username (string)
SessionId (string)
PartOfAppAccessed 
(
Key (int), 
 Name (string), 
Description (string)
Time (DateTime)
) 
}

But while displaying this data, I want to group rows based on session Id's. So my output has to be in this structure

{

### Usagedata

Username (string)
SessionId (string)
Time (DateTime)
PartOfAppAccessed 
(
Key (int), 
 Name (string), 
Description (string)
Time (DateTime)
), 
 (
Key (int), 
 Name (string), 
Description (string)
Time (DateTime)
), 
 (
Key (int), 
 Name (string), 
Description (string)
Time (DateTime)
)

}

So my question is - How do I group different rows from the same IQueryable based on some condition (such as common sessionId's in this case)?

Comment: Club rows? Do you mean group them (club as in group) or filter them (club as in a stick for knocking some out)?

Comment: club is not a very common term in data processing. Do you want to join them, group them, order them?

Comment: @DannyVarod - the first, club as in group them.

Comment: @MareInfinitus - I meant group them, based on common values in a column..

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you want to [group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grouped_data) your `UsageData` instances based on their `SessionId` and `UserName`. The code:

```
IQueryable<UsageData> usageData = ... ;
var groupedUsageData = usageData.GroupBy(x => new { x.SessionId, x.Username });
```

Then, you can work with a single group like the following:

```
var singleGroup = groupedUsageData.ElementAt(0);
string sessionId = singleGroup.Key.SessionId;
string name = singleGroup.Key.Name;

IEnumerable<string> accessedAppsNames = singleGroup.Select(x => x.PartOfAppAccessed.Name);
```

A few notes that came to mind:

- Since you can probably directly map the session to the user, it may be unnecessary to store both `SessionId` and `Username` in your `UsageData` objects. Perhaps it would be better to store only `SessionId` and get the name of the user from some other table?
- It doesn't make a sense for grouped `UsageData` to contain `Time` property. What value would it have? In your original object (before the grouping takes place), the `Time` property is only declared on `PartOfAppAccessed` object.

Comment: Maybe that singleGroup / Select part will not work. At least in my example, it seems that singleGroup has no PartOfAppAccess member / property.